# bitmap corrupted when use in PaintEventArgs.DrawImage

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawimage, corrupt

My program have two part, in First section we create a bitmap like this:

```
frameBitmap = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, pConvertedFrame->linesize[0], PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, new IntPtr(pConvertedFrame->data_0));
```

this part work good, and there isn't any problem here.

at second section, that is at "OnPaint" event function for my "userControl", frameBitmap would be used like below:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(frameBitmap, drawArea, x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

I must tell that, my control will be refreshed some times. "OnPaint" supported with this attribute:
`[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]`
and `try{}catch{}` .
but some times corrupted with this exception:
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupted."
I know "frameBitmap" is corrupted.

well, I was fix it with this solution; Instead first section use this code:

```
Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, pConvertedFrame->linesize[0], PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, new IntPtr(pConvertedFrame->data_0));
frameBitmap = new Bitmap(temp);
```

Well, now my question is: Why?
I'm solved it, but I'm not found like my solution or like my problem, and I'm solved it perfectly creative. but I don't know how this happened ;))

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about the `pConvertedFrame` ? is it released before the bitmap is released?

Comment: When modifying bitmapdata, I always recomment using [LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: bitmap was lock with an Object in both parts. and I'm know 'pConvertedFrame' not released.